# 'Undefined' bug in react native map function for object array

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
Object {
  "id": 172,
  "user_na": "User 1",
}
Object {
  "id": 173,
  "user_na": "User 2",
}
Object {
  "id": 174,
  "user_na": "User 3",
}
Object {
  "id": 175,
  "user_na": "User 4",
}
```

This is my array and I want to get each `id` and `user_na` for which I've used map function.

```
data.map((dataMapped) => {
   console.log(data.id);
   console.log(data.user_na);
});
```

But I'm getting an output like

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

I expect to see output like,

```
172
User 1
173
User 2
.........
```

My array [] name *data* which is a `const`. I'm extracting the info from SQLite database and pushing into data array, which gives me the above format

```
const data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     data.push(results.rows.item(i));
}
```

Since I'm new to asking questions on stackoverflow, I don't know how to properly ask

Comment: `console.log(dataMapped.user_na);`

Comment: You have to use the variable declared for mapping, in your example you have to console.log `dataMapped.user_na`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used dataMapped in your map.

```
data.map((dataMapped) => {
   console.log(dataMapped.id);
   console.log(dataMapped.user_na);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used wrong variable inside your loop.
Please Replace "data.id" with "dataMapped.id" and "data.user_na" with "dataMapped.user_na"

```
data.map((dataMapped) => {
  console.log(dataMapped.id);
  console.log(dataMapped.user_na);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

dataMapped is each single entity in your data array in your case

```
 data.map((dataMapped) => {
   console.log(dataMapped.id);
   console.log(dataMapped.user_na);
});
```

ex

```
arr=[{name:"1"},{name:"2"}]

arr.map((dataMapped)=>
{
console.log(dataMapped.name)
})

1
2
```

where dataMapped is object in that you required